# How can I display specific range of items in an ASP.NET MVC view passed from ViewBag in array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my `HomeController.cs` I have:

```
public IActionResult Places ()
{
    string [] places = {"AA", "BB", "CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH","II","JJ"};
    ViewBag.fav = places;
}
```

In `Places.cshtml` I want to display only 3 elements of the array passed in `ViewBag.fav` - that is AA, BB and CC

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">We Love These</li>
    @foreach(var x in ViewBag.fav)
    {
        <li> @x </li>
    }
</ul>
```

and I want to display other elements here

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">Our Fav</li>
    @foreach(var x in ViewBag.fav)
    {
        <li> @x </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: why don't you pass only first 3 : places.Take(3);

Comment: As a general rule, the view should be as simple as possible and contain **next to no logic** - so if you want to display something - pass it over to the view in the view model - if you **don't want to show** something - then just **don't pass it** to the view

Comment: I dont know other way i am using ViewBag to pass data from controller to View. I m using like 12 ViewBag in loop and displaying in View

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on your last comment `pass many data to pass in the view` you should then use a view model.

Something like:

```
   public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<string> Places { get; set; }

        public List<string> MostFavoritePlaces => Places.Take(3).ToList();

        public List<string> FavoritePlaces => Places.Skip(3).ToList();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Places = new List<string>{ "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "JJ" };
        }
    }
```

Then in your controller you can return the view model to the page as:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View(viewModel);
    }
```

The view will receive a parameter of type ViewModel like this:

```
@model ViewModel;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item active">We Love These</li>
        @foreach (var x in Model.MostFavoritePlaces)
        {
            <li> @x </li>
        }
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item active">Our Fav</li>
        @foreach (var x in Model.FavoritePlaces)
        {
            <li> @x </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Now the class ViewModel is responsible for the data structure that will be rendered into  the view. 
It can have more properties in order to handle more data being sent to the view. 
It encapsulates the data and logic.

The controller is responsible for creating an instance of the model and pass it to the view.

The view has little logic - simply receive the model - and just renders the data that has been passed.

Comment: thanks buddy that helped me alot. But what changes do i need to make if I am using _context for Data Access from Database. I have Hotels table and I want to group hotels  based on Category in Index page.

Comment: Need to have more info - lets talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207053/alex-leo)

Comment: i dont have reputation to chat.. ;-(

Comment: Given you write access now